# How to automate git merge to not prompt to confirm the commit message?

Tags: git, automation

I'm trying to do some automation scripts using git, simple things like updating submodules, moving to proper tags etc, but one of the problems I'm now finding is that git now forces you to confirm a merge message. Is there any way to squelch this behavior from happening?

Comment: What merge command are you running, in what circumstances, to get this behaviour? Also please give the Git version.

Comment: @DanHulme Already sussed this thanks to a comment below. I was using git 1.7.10, and basically *any* merge, pull operation would result in an interactive prompt. --no-edit and exporting the GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no solved it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To prevent git from promting you for an commit message on mac add this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile ([read more about the difference between the two files](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html))

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
```

Then in your terminal type:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to reload your bash-file and continue without any interference.

Comment: Editing the `~/.bashrc`, `~/bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` (or whatever is applicable for your terminal) will ensure the change is persisted into *new* terminal sessions. I would mention though that explicitly sourcing the file is not necessary, and could have unintended consequences if the user had added contents in there they do not which to execute twice per session. Instead of sourcing it, we could also simply execute `export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` directly in the current terminal session.

Comment: `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` does not work after conflict resolution for `git merge --continue`. Editor still pops up.

Answer (score 77):

You can add the `--no-edit` switch to `git-merge` and it will not ask you to confirm the merge message.

Comment: Newer version (>=1.7.10) of git merge default enter into an interactive session. You have to add --no-edit argument or add environment variable GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no to suppress an interactive session

Comment: @linquize, I wish you put this as an answer-- the environmental was EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Use this command:

```
git merge other_branch --commit --no-edit
```

`--commit` to do commit automatically right after the merge.

`--no-edit` to prevent showing up the commit message editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the editor to not show it up by replacing `vim` with `cat` or `true`, e.g.:

```
GIT_EDITOR=true git merge branch_name
```

This will populate the merge message automatically.